# Boot parameters

Tags: linux, boot, grub, kernel, grub2

Is there a way to find out with what parameters did the kernel boot?

For example if I specify noexec=off at the grub command line? Can I see this sort of info after the system has finished booting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string of boot parameters the kernel was booted with is stored in the `/proc/cmdline` file.  ([`/proc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) is  a virtual filesystem that contains information about the running system and processes.  There is a lot of useful information in there!)

To display it on a terminal, just run:

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```